# Hadoop INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server localhost/127.0.0.1:9000

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-partitioning

I read other posts about the HDFS configuration problem with Hadoop. However, none of them was helpful. So, I post my question. I followed [this](http://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/how-to-configure-apache-hadoop-in-standalone-mode) tutorial for hadoop v1.2.1. When I am running hadoop fs -ls command I've got this error:

```
16/08/29 15:20:35 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server:   localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
```

My core-site.xml file is:

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/mnt/miczfs/hadoop/tmp/${user.name}</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Also, my hdfs-site.xml file is as follow:

```
<configuration>
<property>
 <name>dfs.replication</name>
 <value>1</value>
    </property>
<property>
   <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
    <value>/mnt/miczfs/hadoop/hdfs/${user.name}/namenode</value>
</property>
 <property>
    <name>dfs.secondary.http.address</name>
    <value>localhost:0</value>
 </property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
    <value>/mnt/miczfs/hadoop/hdfs/${user.name}/datanode</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.address</name>
   <value>localhost:0</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.http.address</name>
   <value>localhost:0</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.ipc.address</name>
   <value>localhost:0</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

and the /etc/hosts is this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4  localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6    localhost6.localdomain6
 172.31.1.1      micrasrelmond.local micrasrelmond #Generated-by-micctrl
 172.31.1.1      mic0.local mic0 #Generated-by-micctrl
```

If it is possible, please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check whether namenode is running or not by jps command. if it is running then format name node by the command bin/hadoop namenode -format.

In order to avoid formatting namenode after every restart change hdfs default directory to some other location.